# aligning list items of equal width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to align all the list items of equal width....
following is jsfiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/277Yd/

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center ">Courses</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center oval-shape img-responsive">
        <a>Post Graduate</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center oval-shape img-responsive">
        <a>Graduate</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center oval-shape img-responsive">
        <a>Honours</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center oval-shape img-responsive">
        <a>Tiger Studio</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center oval-shape img-responsive">
        <a>Others</a>
    </div>
</div>

.oval-shape a {
    background: #FF9900;
    border-radius:50px;
    padding:10px;
    /*      background-image: url('../images/button.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x; */
}
```

Comment: Hi, they seem equally aligned.. can you clarify please?

Comment: all items should have same width...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `a` from your CSS so instead of `.oval-shape a {` write `.oval-shape {`

Add a `width` to your `oval-shape` class to adjust the width, for example `width:15%;`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/277Yd/2/)